# postgresql version won't change from default

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

mac os x lion 10.7.4

psql --version -> psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5

I want to install latest version and run my rails app with it.

I do

```
brew install postgresql

it is installed here: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4  

initdb /usr/local/var/postgres

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

I get:

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
```

running postgres --version

```
 -> 9.1.4
```

postgres -p 5433

```
 postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
 You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` and change the `port` directive to use a different port number like `5433`. Then start the new Pg instance as you did before.

You can now connect to the 9.1 instance by specifying a different port in your Rails configuration.

Comment: i changed the port and ran the server again but its not changing. can you please give me a bit more details on how to do this.

Comment: @Beamon ... did you change your rails setup to connect to the new port in `database.yml`?

Comment: I'm not even connecting to the 9.1.4 instance yet... after I change the conf file to port # to 5433 and save. Starting the pg instance is not connecting to the right instance. Don't I need to connect to the right instance before I worry about my database.yml and rails configuration?

Comment: @Beamon Connecting with *what*? Do you mean `psql`? Struggling to understand your comment. You need to (a) Start the new Pg on a different port; and (b) connect to it by specifying the new port. For `psql` that'd be `psql -p 5433` for example.

Comment: running: psql --version gets 9.0.5 and postgres --version gets 9.1.4. I added more info above based on some of the things you have been suggesting. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Beamon Run the version of `psql` that was installed by the new PostgreSQL. You may need to set your `PATH` or use an explicit path. To get the version of the *server* you're connected to use `select version();`

Answer (score 3):

In MAC:

```
brew link --overwrite -f postgresql@9.6
```

will change default psql version on terminal psql command.

You will also find all postgresql version folders in /usr/local/Cellar/

Examples:

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.3_4

/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6